# Density of an even algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, clifford-algebras

I’m trying to prove that if a set $S$ is dense in the even subalgebra $A^+$ of a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded algebra $A$ then $S$ is dense in the algebra $A$. But since density is not transitive, I don’t know how to proceed.

¿How can I prove this assertion?

Thank you!

Note: Here $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is the boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: How is $A$ topologized?

Comment: $A$ has the standard topology (of $C$)

Comment: @AHusain $A$ is constructed as a tensor product.

Comment: $A^+$ is dense in $A+$, but typically not dense in $A$.